# Need help writing data to json in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, web-scraping

I am webscraping some data and trying to write the scraped data to a json file using c# newtonsoft.Json.

I get stuck when writing the data to the Json file in my **controller**.
The multidimensional arrays in c# confuse me.

Thanks in advance.

This is an example of the Json file I am trying to create:

```
[
{
    "testmodule1": {
        "name": {
            "required": true,
            "options": [
                "option1",
                "option2"
            ]
        },
        "admin": {
            "required": true,
            "options": [
                "option1",
                "option2"
            ]
        },
        "path": {
            "required": true,
            "options": [
                "option1",
                "option2"
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "testmodule2": {
        "name": {
            "required": true,
            "options": [
                "option1",
                "option2"
            ]
        },
        "server": {
            "required": false,
            "options": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "required": true,
            "options": [
                "option1",
                "option2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
]
```

These are my classes:

```
    public class JsonData
{
    public Dictionary<string, JsonParameters> modulename { get; set; }
}

public class JsonParameters
{
    public JsonParametersData parameter { get; set; }
}
public class JsonParametersData
{
    public bool required { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller, here is where I get stuck. **the name modulename does not exist in the current context**:

```
public class WebscrapeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Webscrape
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            List<JsonData> data = new List<JsonData>();
            data.Add(new JsonData()
            {
                modulename = new Dictionary<string, JsonParameters>()
                {
                    modulename.Add("testmodule1", new JsonParameters()
                    {
                        parameter = new JsonParametersData()
                        {
                            required = true,
                            options = new List<string>()
                            {
                                "option1",
                                "option2"
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToArray());

            //write string to file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(
                @"C:mypath",
                json);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Note that the property names `"testmodule1"` and `"testmodule2"` as well as `"name"`, `"admin"`, `"path"`, `"server"` are arbitrary; they differ for each array.

Comment: Where are the multi-dimensional arrays? And what is not working?

Comment: 1) Are the names `"testmodule1"` and `"testmodule2"` predetermined or arbitrary?  2) Are the names `"name"`, `"admin"`, `"path"`, `"server"` and `"port"` predetermined or arbitrary?

Comment: arbitrary, they different for each array

Comment: The way I am filling up the json arrayis not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the property names `"testmodule1"` and `"testmodule2"` as well as `"name"`, `"admin"`, `"path"`, `"server"` and `"port"` are arbitrary and not known in advance, you need to model your `results` array as a `List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>>>`.  That is because, when serializing a dictionary to JSON using Json.NET, the dictionary keys become JSON property names.

Thus the JSON above can be created as follows:

```
// Allocate results using collection initializer syntax for the lists and for the dictionaries.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer
var results = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>>>()
{
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>>()
    {
        {
            "testmodule1",
            new Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>()
            {
                {
                    "name",
                    new JsonParametersData
                    {
                        required = true,
                        options = new List<string>() { "option1", "option2" },
                    }
                },
                {
                    "admin",
                    new JsonParametersData
                    {
                        required = true,
                        options = new List<string>() { "option1", "option2" },
                    }
                },
                {
                    "path",
                    new JsonParametersData
                    {
                        required = true,
                        options = new List<string>() { "option1", "option2" },
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
};

var moduleName = "testmodule2";
var moduleParameters = new [] { "name", "server", "port" };         

// Now add another result, allocating the dictionary with collection initializer syntax also
results.Add(new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>>()
    {
        {
            moduleName,
            // Loop through the parameters and convert them to a dictionary,
            // where the parameter name is the key and the corresponding JsonParametersData is the value
            moduleParameters
                .ToDictionary(n => n,
                              n => new JsonParametersData
                              {
                                  required = true, 
                                  options = new List<string>() { "option1", "option2" },
                              })
        }
    });

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented);
```

Notes:

- For documentation on how dictionaries are serialized to JSON, see [Serialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) and [Serialization Guide: Dictionaries and Hashtables](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Dictionarys).
- I am initializing the outermost `List<T>` using [collection initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers).
- I am also initializing the dictionaries using collection initializer syntax as shown in [*How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer).
- Given a collection of parameter names and a way to get the `JsonParametersData` for each one (not shown in the question), the LINQ extension method [`Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) can be used to construct a `Dictionary<string, JsonParametersData>` from the parameter collection.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mhETF5).

Comment: Amazing work! This really helps me out, thanks, my friend!
How would you go when building a loop for the number of parameters? My data sometimes contains more or less than 3 parameters.

Comment: @ChakirBelhaj - which ones are the parameters?  The `"testmodule1"` properties, the `"name"`/`"server"`/`"path"` properties, or the `"option1", "option2"` array entries?

Comment: name, server, path, port, properties.  @dbc

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach using Newtonsoft JObject.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/TdFDQc

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JArray array = new JArray();

        // Module 1
        JObject parameter = new JObject();
        AddParameter(parameter, "name", true, new[] { "option1", "option2" });
        AddParameter(parameter, "admin", true, new[] { "option1", "option2" });
        AddParameter(parameter, "path", false, new[] { "option1", "option2", "option3" });

        JObject module = new JObject();
        module.Add("testmodule1", parameter);

        array.Add(module);

        // Module 2
        parameter = new JObject();
        AddParameter(parameter, "name", true, new[] { "option1", "option2" });
        AddParameter(parameter, "server", false, Array.Empty<string>());
        AddParameter(parameter, "port", true, new[] { "option1", "option2", "option3" });

        module = new JObject();
        module.Add("testmodule2", parameter);

        array.Add(module);

        // Display result
        var json = array.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(json);        
    }

    static void AddParameter(JObject jObject, string name, bool required, string[] options)
    {
        JObject parameterProperties = new JObject();
        parameterProperties.Add("required", JToken.FromObject(required));
        parameterProperties.Add("options", JToken.FromObject(options));

        jObject.Add(name, parameterProperties);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!